# String variable in conjunction with wildcard character usage in SQL query via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to run `SQL query` in `VBA`. `table` name is `t`. I am putting wildcard characters to find any matching entries. However, I get `type mismatch error`.

I have tried following:

```
Dim j as string
Dim SQL1 as string

j = "ED"

SQL1 = "SELECT t.ID, t.Name " _
       &"FROM t " _
       & WHERE (((t.Name) Like " * " & '" & j & "' & " * ")); "
```

Can someone help me where I am making a mistake here.

Comment: Remove the spaces around the stars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to view your original code in any code editor equipped with VBA syntax highlighting, you'll soon discover the imbalance in single & double-quotes in your string concatenation - this can even be demonstrated using the syntax highlighting on this site:

```vb
SQL1 = "SELECT t.ID, t.Name " _
   &"FROM t " _
   & WHERE (((t.Name) Like " * " & '" & j & "' & " * ")); "
```

Notice that `WHERE (((t.Name) Like` is not displayed as a string since you're missing an opening double quote on that line, and anything following the first single quote is regarded as a comment.

Since only variable data requires concatenation, your definition of the `SQL1` variable can be greatly simplified to the following:

```vb
SQL1 = "SELECT t.ID, t.Name FROM t WHERE t.Name Like '*" & j & "*'"
```

Or alternatively, you can use double-quotes in the following way to yield double-quotes in the resulting concatenated string:

```vb
SQL1 = "SELECT t.ID, t.Name FROM t WHERE t.Name Like ""*" & j & "*"""
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: (position of the asterixes and apostrophes is important !)

```
SQL1 = "SELECT t.ID, t.Name " _
& "FROM t " _
& "WHERE t.Name Like '*" & j & "*'"
```

Comment: Still missing double-quotes on the last line.

Comment: And it still has additional space between the wildcard and the variable. It won't work.

Comment: Edited the answer by @libert to fix quotes and space issue.

Comment: @Lone: your version was still not working, edited again and now tested OK